# in Selenium java, sendkeys function is not entering the data but locating the exact location

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

in Selenium java,  sendkeys function is not entering the data but locating the exact location.
Website: https://www.makemytrip.com/

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".langCard.fixedCard.bounceAni>span")).click();
    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#fromCity"));
    
    from.sendKeys("ben");
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert the search word there you need first to click the form element and then to insert the search word into the search input.
Something like this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".langCard.fixedCard.bounceAni>span"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#fromCity"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[@for='fromCity']//input"))).sendKeys("ben");
```

Comment: ,Getting this Error:                                                                                                        
       Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input data-cy="fromCity" id="fromCity" type="text" class="fsw_inputField lineHeight36 latoBlack font30" readonly="" value="Delhi"> is not clickable at point (245, 255). Other element would receive the click: <div data-cy="outsideModal" class="loginModal displayBlock modalLogin dynHeight personal "></div>

Comment: Well, I see. Try adding some dummy delay of 1 second there before the last code line

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in headless mode? If not you can change the ExpectedConditions in the code snippet above to

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".langCard.fixedCard.bounceAni>span"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#fromCity"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='fromCity']//input"))).sendKeys("ben");
```